# Random yellow blocks in text file after reloading & discarding it

Tags: linux, ubuntu, text, editor, text-editor

I was making notes using the Ubuntu 23.04 Text Editor and had it opened in 2 tabs. I made changes in one tab and saved it and when I opened original tab, I was told "changes had been made... Discard & Reload".

Once I reloaded, I had these random yellow blocks appearing in the text file:
[image: img]

What are these yellow blocks and why did they appear? I can get rid of them just by backspacing but I would like to know what they are and what made them appear?

Comment: How is this a question about programming?